# Google Maps Javascript API - places.AutocompleteService - getPlacePredictions returns wrong distance_meters, when certain criteria are met

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Google Maps Javascript API version 3.44.5

I call getPlacePredictions to get predictions from some user input, 'origin' biased, and 'address' type. The prediction distance_meters is wrong under certain circumstances: When the input doesn't correspond to an existent street number, but is closed enough so the engine is able to estimate location. Proof of wrong distance: Take the returned place_id, use Geocoder to obtain geometry.location, finally calc distance between coords. In this example we get 547 vs 2481 meters.

Also, please conside that Villate 250 returns **547** meters (wrong),  the **same** distance of Villate 280, and the **same** of Villate 350... But Villate 456 returns 2390 meters (correct)... And then again Villate 480 returns **547** meters (wrong) and so on...

Bug ? Am i misinterpreting something ? Thanks

```
const OriginLat = -34.52211;
const OriginLon = -58.499669;
const exampleInput = "villate 250";

var service = new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

service.getPlacePredictions({  input: exampleInput
                                                   , type: ["address"]
                                                   , componentRestrictions: { country: 'ar' }
                                                   , origin: new google.maps.LatLng( OriginLat, OriginLon )
                                                   , radius: 1
}, displaySuggestions);

const displaySuggestions = function(predictions, status) {
               
    // Values
    console.log(predictions[0].place_id);
    // EkBDYXJsb3MgVmlsbGF0ZSAyNTAsIE9saXZvcywgUHJvdmluY2lhIGRlIEJ1ZW5vcyBBaXJlcywgQXJnZW50aW5hIlESTwo0CjIJc8WRg0SxvJURdeB0wGKPz_caHgsQ7sHuoQEaFAoSCb-oQzIdsbyVEYvJh6S0OZzZDBD6ASoUChIJz6lHjCixvJURF-aUHiYnCg4

    console.log(predictions[0].distance_meters);
    // 547m
};

geocoder.geocode({placeId: place_id}, geocoderResult);

const geocoderResult = function(results, status) {

  let resultPos = results[0].geometry.location;
  console.log(resultPos);
  // -34.51032,-58.476673

  // Distance Recalc
  distance_meters = fncLocalDistance(resultPos.lat(), resultPos.lng(), OriginLat, OriginLon);
  // 2481m
};

// Distance between coords
function fncLocalDistance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
        if ((lat1 == lat2) && (lon1 == lon2)) {return 0}

        let radlat1 = Math.PI * lat1/180;
        let radlat2 = Math.PI * lat2/180;
        let theta = lon1-lon2;
        let radtheta = Math.PI * theta/180;
        let dist = Math.sin(radlat1) * Math.sin(radlat2) + Math.cos(radlat1) * Math.cos(radlat2) * Math.cos(radtheta);
        if (dist > 1) {dist = 1}
        dist = Math.acos(dist);
        dist = dist * 180/Math.PI;
        dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
        dist = dist * 1.609344 * 1000;
       
        return dist;
}
```